# EventSource long respond time and multiple data receive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-sent-events, eventsource

Currently i implement EventSource (client for listen to Server Sent Event) at React. Below is my code example.

```
import React from "react";
let es = {};


class Layout extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    let $$ = this;
    es = new EventSource(`${urlConfig.SSE_HOST}subscribe`);
    es.addEventListener("rule-event", function (e) {
      const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
      console.log("DATA Event  => ", data);
      $$.props.addRuleEvent(data.name, data.value);

      const rule = data.name.split(':');
      const ruleName = rule[0];
      const ruleType = rule[1];

      $$.props.addLatestEvent(`${ruleName}:${ruleType}`, data.value);
    });

   componentWillUnmount() {
     es.close();
   }
}
```

After receive data from SSE, i will push data to redux and consume later. But now i am having new problem, after a little long time about half/one hour the problem occur(i keep open the browser tab, CHROME). The problem is the data will be received multiple, sometime even 3 or 4 data. Even when my SSE only send one data.

Second problem, sometime my client(EventSource) take a long time to listen SSE

Does anybody experience this bug before? Or there is something wrong with my code?